# Help Needed for Broadcom Testing

Tags: support

it's your crazy mod here. I am in need of Ubuntu users that have a BCM43XX Broadcom Wireless Card. For the Broadcom models you can go ahead and read

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

What we need right now and before 14.04 reaches the release date is for anyone with a Broadcom model shown in the link above to send me an email saying what model they have, what Ubuntu version they are using and what driver they are actually using for it. This will help clean the answer a bit and make an up-to-date answer for all of us. Something along the lines of:

**Ubuntu Version**: 13.10 64 Bit
**Broadcom Model**: BCM4312 Rev 01
**Driver**: wl
**Problems**: The connections drops every 4 minutes. I tried another driver but...

To check which Broadcom Model you have, simply run the following line on your terminal:

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

That should create the following output:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 03)
```

To see what driver you are using type the following in the terminal:

If your wireless card is **wlan0**

```
ls /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver/module/drivers
```

In the case is another simply change the wlan0 to the other name (wlan1, eth2...)

Another general way would be to type `lshw -c network` that should output all your network devices with their respective logical network names and drivers.

Lastly, send any input you have on problems you had with that specific model, issues you are experiencing and anything else you feel could help in create a better guide for the Broadcom Wireless installation.

Thank you very much for your time and help and I hope to see many of you help out by sending their emails to luisalvarado@ubuntu.com

I already have a list of people to thank for the patient since January and new users that have had great ideas about how to handle all the Broadcom related questions. Again thank you all and let's see how great we will do to unified all/most Broadcom issues.

Follow us on: http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/help-needed-for-broadcom-testing

Comment: You should also post this on Discourse/Ubuntu forums if you want a lot of responses.

Comment: @Seth Actually was posting on both ^^.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado - feel free to edit my copy of your broadcom answer on UL or ping me if it changes significantly.